# --receive-pack set and getting syntax error

Tags: git, bash, openssh

I've been trying to set up an openssh git server but ended up trying to solve this error literally all night. My first issue was `git-receive-pack: command not found`. I'm pretty sure that I have solved that issue but I am running into a syntax error after I execute this command.

```
$ git push --receive-pack=/home origin master
MJLaukala@127.0.0.1's password:
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected `('
bash: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/home 'project.git''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any information at all would be helpful. Thanks in advance.